# Can't apply font inside rails mail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have this font called **EngraversGothicBT**. I can't find why this font is not applied on mail which is sent right after user is registered.

I have following css for that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>noname</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>

      @font-face {
        font-family: 'EngraversGothicBT';
        src: url('/assets/EngraversGothicBT.eot');
        src: url('/assets/EngraversGothicBT.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('/assets/EngraversGothicBT.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('/assets/EngraversGothicBT.woff') format('woff'),
             url('/assets/EngraversGothicBT.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('/assets/EngraversGothicBT.svg#EngraversGothicBT') format('svg');
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;
  }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 967.99px){
        .central-image {
          height: auto !important;
        }
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 692px){
        .central-image a {
          height: 110px !important;
        }
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 620px){
        .main-table {
          padding: 0 15px !important;
        }
        td.border {
          padding:30px 35% 0 !important;
        }
        td.custom-height {
          line-height: 0.8 !important;
        }
        td.footer-border {
          padding:3px 40% 0 !important;
        }
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 490px){
        .central-image a {
          height: 98px !important;
        }
        .table-subtitle p {
          font-size: 15px !important;
        }
        .table-with-text p {
          font-size: 12px !important;
        }
        .footer a {
          font-size: 11px !important;
        }
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 410px){
        .central-image a {
          height: 85px !important;
        }
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 380px){
        .table-welcome {
          margin-top: 55px !important;
        }
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 370px){
        .central-image a {
          height: 70px !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body style="margin:0; padding:0; font-family:'EngraversGothicBT', sans-serif; font-weight: 400; font-size: 18px; color: #202220;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
      <%= yield %>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

All of fonts are located inside /assets/fonts path, so i believe that src path should be right. I don't know what i am missing here.

Comment: Did you get any **404 no route matches errors** in the server log?

Comment: Use web fonts or Base64 encode your fonts. Here is a thread also https://css-tricks.com/custom-fonts-in-emails/ (or use images)